# Crawling iframe using beautifulsoup and selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I would crawl the web site where it has the iframe.

see http://dart.fss.or.kr/dsaf001/main.do?rcpNo=20150515001896. It has 2 options at chrome browser.("view page source" and "view frame source" either.)

But accessing the url using Beautiful Soup, urllib2 or selenium gave me only the page source without iframe

How could I access to iframe source which can be seen at the chrome?

The below code is for accessing page source of that website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://dart.fss.or.kr/dsaf001/main.do?rcpNo=20150515001896"
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)

#or

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source

#show only the page sources
```

Comment: http://www.assertselenium.com/webdriver/handling-iframes-using-webdriver/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply solved by accessing below url.

http://dart.fss.or.kr/report/viewer.do?rcpNo=20150515001896&dcmNo=4671059&eleId=17&offset=1015699&length=132786&dtd=dart3.xsd